Valid json string resulting in error when trying to import into postgresql table
Currently using postgresql in pgAdmin 4 to import some csvs into my tables - I've never done this before but none of the jsonb columns are - for reference, this is just data I've been sent to practice with.
To try to get to the bottom of this, I've created a table test with columns 'id' [type = uuid] and 'testjson' [type = jsonb].
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL: Token "thiskey" is invalid.
CONTEXT: JSON data, line 1: {thiskey...
COPY test2, line 2, column properties: " {thiskey:thisvalue}"

My raw data in the csv looks like (cut down to one line to make simpler):
id,testjson
00552b94-7b13-491e-83d1-6cbebe1b7613, "{""thiskey"":""thisvalue""}"

and I have the options selected as shown in the settings.

Every time I hit "ok" on import, I get the following error:
I know there are other questions on stackoverflow addressing this error but they all seem to be doing it once the data is successfully imported, which is a hurdle I am failing to overcome.

Should it be "{\"thiskey`":`"thisvalue`"}"` in the csv

its probably ' not ` as the escape

You can clear the ESCAPE field in that pgAdmin import dialog or change it to the same character " as the one you set in QUOTE field, and it should work, as per the hint underneath it: "The default is the same as the QUOTE value (so that the quoting chracter is doubled if it appears in the data)." That way copy will read "{""thiskey"":""thisvalue""}" as the {"thiskey":"thisvalue"} you want.

Are you using csv or text format  in the General tab?

@Zegarek Please make that an answer

@AdrianKlaver Quote option worked, so it must be csv mode. It's not available in default text mode.

You can clear the ESCAPE field in that pgAdmin import dialog or change it to the same character " as the one you set in QUOTE field, and it should work, as per the hint underneath it:

Escape
Specifies the character that should appear before a data character that matches the QUOTE value. The default is the same as the QUOTE value (so that the quoting chracter is doubled if it appears in the data).

That way copy will read "{""thiskey"":""thisvalue""}" as the {"thiskey":"thisvalue"} you want.

Thanks! Yeah I eventually figure it out - now have run into a problem with a double-double quote in a different line for a json field (""), which as far as I can tell is just invalid json so looks like I'll need to do some fixing to the data.
